# Too many arguments with poetry install

Tags: python-poetry

I am facing some issues with Poetry.

I am getting the following error while trying to execute pytest:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coverage'**
But when I try to install with poetry like this: `poetry install coverage` I get the following error message:
**Too many arguments.**

Anyone knows how to solve it?

I tried to execute `poetry install coverage` but got only the message **Too many arguments.**

Comment: Try `poetry add coverage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poetry install` doesn't accept any arguments. It only installs the dependencies described in `pyproject.toml`.

Instead you need to use `poetry add` to add a new dependency. Check out [the documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/) for more details. In fact, you should always refer to the official documentation for guidance in situations like this.